# multiboot boot order

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 18.04 as my primary operating system on sda1. I have installed other operating systems, in order to support members of the family. On separate drives or partitions.

Each time I install a new os it takes position 1 at boot.

How do I get ubuntu first? and can I stop it happening

To Clarify for  PRATAP

The Ubuntu machine is 64 bit AMD based and uses Bios, Grub2. This is the boot sequence I want to maintain in grub. Currently I set the boot drive for each of the supported linuxes on drive sdc which keeps them away from the default sda boot. But means I have to select a boot drive at power on, and means the next time grub-update or a ubuntu upgrade run they will be in the sda boot/grub/grub.cfg.

I know I can install grub-customizer but would prefer not to.

Further
The machine I wish to modify is BIOS and it is that grub I wish to modify.
The reason I don't want to use grub-customizer is because I used in linux lite some time ago but it was impossible to fully remove it.

Doing as you suggest was my first thought but I was concerned that would put the other oses at the top of the boot selections which I'm trying to avoid as re-installing linux is a pain to include all the extras I've added over the years.

Are you saying that having installed the extra OS in a different boot drive then updating grub in the original (sda) will put the new OS at the end?

I've come across a link at  "Grub2/CustomMenus - Community Help Wiki
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus".

which sounds as if it does the job but is tricky to do.

Comment: you mean in grub options or in UEFI boot options??

Comment: The machine is BIOS but one of the others id UEFI. The order of boot is required for the BIOS machine as the others only have 1 o/s installed

Comment: If you mixed UEFI & BIOS installs, you can only boot from UEFI boot menu. Grub will only boot other installs in same boot mode. With Ubuntu you can install with 'ubiquity -b' to not install grub2's boot loader, but must have grub in same boot mode installed with another system & then update it to include new install. If BIOS you can put different boot loaders in MBR of each drive. You really should have all installs in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS.You can also reinstall grub to MBR of sda for install in sda1. With BIOS you can choose with MBR to install grub into. With UEFI that does not work.

Comment: "I know I can install grub-customizer but would prefer not to." What is the reason?

Comment: In BIOS/Legacy multi-boot installations the last installed OS takes over the bootloader. If we're talking about desktop Linux you're likely to be using Grub. Simply boot the OS you want to be in charge (Ubuntu?) and reinstall Grub to the booting drive (sda?) and update Grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update-grub put the new installation at the end of the list, my concern was unjustified. Thanks for the help  PRATAP .

It seems a long way around but life's short and that works!